# DialogflowのDialogflowApp.getUserにてユーザー情報を取得できない

Tags: node.js, firebase

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/ApiAiApp
上記の公式サイトを参考に、Dialogflow上でアクセストークンを取得したいと思っていますが、DialogflowApp.getUser()の結果がnullとなってしまいます。

アカウントリンキングにより、クライアント側ではGoogleアカウントで認証済みです。
DialogFlowのSimulatorのDEBUGタブでは「assistantToAgentDebug.assistantToAgentJson.user」
に値が入っており、
req.body.originalRequest.data.user.accessToken
で直接参照する分にはアクセストークンを取得できました。

DialogflowApp.getUser()でユーザー情報を取得するには
下記定義で誤っている個所などがありますでしょうか。

※Fullfilmentを利用し、index.jsにロジックを記載しています。

＜ソース＞
■index.js

```
'use strict';

const App = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;

exports.testMethod = (req, res) => {

  // 結果がnullとなる
  const app = new App({req, res});
  let user = app.getUser();
  console.log('User is ' + user);

  // アクセストークンが取得できる
  let accessToken = req.body.originalRequest.data.user.accessToken;
  console.log('accessToken is ' + accessToken);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': 'success!', 'displayText': 'success!' }));
};
```

■package.json

```
{
  "name": "testMethod",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本件、下記コードとすることで解決しました。

```
const app = new App({request:req, response:res});
```

ご協力ありがとうございました。